# Having an private InputMethod

Tags: android, keyboard

I do a bit of research right now. I spoke with one of our Designer about an special login layout which mimics an Numberpad. As it looks not like Android support such Layout that seems reasonable to me. I played on the N5 android:inputType property on a single EditText go get a better understanding what can be customized:

```
<EditText
    android:text="1234"
    android:hint="enter your pin code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"/>
```

Which results in an keyboard like this:

[image]

When i click on the , or - Keys nothing happens, why that ? I tried also

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"

android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

i still can't use that keys! Why their get shown ?

I would like to have an Keyboard which only shows 01234567890 BACKBUTTON OK

If im correct, this cant be archived using the InputType property. So i may should create some kind of custom keyboard layout.

Beside i still thinking about doing it more the Android Way. So i never wrote a custom keyboard myself, because i never had to do so.

I read [updating-applications-for-on-screen](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) to have a basic clue how that works. But questions
left:

Can i define an Input which is always private just for the specific Application ?

And if yes, how can this be done ?

Is it worth the effort for a very small use case ?

If i look at the Native Call APP there use an custom layout to have more control about the look and feel. I understand why their do it this way. Anyway what you think about this ? There are usecases where i makes quite sense to use an simple ...lets say gridlayout to have a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, instead of using this. I found much better approach which works for me. I use an [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) for doing what i need. I fits better my needs as i need some special kind of Keyboard which can be part of the Layout anyway. First i thought thats bad for UX but after talking to the Design guy, it just makes sense to use it in this special case. Because we really can define easy which key needs to be displayed, also I18N works better with this approach then a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Different IMEs show different layout depending on the inputType, and in this case LatinIME (or Google Keyboard) handles number/numberSigned/numberDecimal using the same layout but blocks certain key.  If the user installs another keyboard, the user may or may not see different layout for the different inputTypes.

As for can you create an App specific IME, you can if you do it like the AOSP dialer by defining your own view/layout and handle key events.  But if you want to do it like a full IME (by extending InputMethodService class, add intent filter for android.view.InputMethod in AndroidManifest, etc), then the IME becomes public and the user needs to enable it through system language settings UI.

Comment: How can i define that the custom keyboard layout is used when i declare some EditTest ?

Comment: The easiest way without going through the pain of hit testing edittext, determine when to show/hide keyboard is just always show it as part of your view.  Maintain a text buffer and On each button click, modify the text buffer then replace text within the edittext with the buffer.  Depending on if you want to handle cursor movements and or backspace, etc, you might need to jump through other hoops.